# How can I reorganize a three-column dataframe with multiple factors into a summary table in R?

Tags: r, pivot-table

I have a table that shows trade flow between countries, with the origin country, destination country, and flow in three different columns. As you might expect, there are multiple combinations of countries and I want to rearrange the table so that the origin countries are the column names and the destination countries are the first column of a data frame.

```
summary_tabl <- me_export_data %>% 
                select(c(country_load, exp_rate, country_dest)) %>%
                group_by(country_load, country_dest) %>%
                summarize(summed_by_dest = sum(exp_rate, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
                arrange(desc(summed_by_dest), country_dest) #%>% 

summary_tabl$country_load <- as.factor(summary_tabl$country_load)
```

it generates a table that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 34 x 3
# Groups:   country_load [6]
   country_load         country_dest summed_by_dest
   <fct>                <fct>                 <dbl>
 1 Qatar                India                 XXX. 
 2 Saudi Arabia         India                 XXX. 
 3 United Arab Emirates India                 XXX. 
 4 Qatar                China                 XXX. 
 5 Kuwait               India                 XXX. 
 6 United Arab Emirates Indonesia             XXX. 
 7 Kuwait               China                 XXX.
 8 Saudi Arabia         Egypt                 XXX.
 9 Saudi Arabia         China                 XXX.
10 Qatar                Indonesia             XXX.
# ... with 24 more rows
```

Again, I want to make a table that has country_load as the column names and the country_dest as the first column. I can do this in excel with a pivot table really easily, but I need to do it in R.

Comment: You can pivot from `long` to `wide` formats via `tidyr::pivot_wider()` https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html

Answer (score 1):

in base R it would be:

```
xtabs(formula = summed_by_dest ~ country_dest + country_load, data = summary_table)
```

but this returns an object of class `table` rather than a `data.frame`.

Keeping it in a data frame (or tibble) would be inconsistent with tidyverse data organization principles. But, if you wanted to use a tidyverse option anyway, you would need to do a `dplyr::group_by` and then `dpylr:summarise` (as you did) followed by the `tidyr::pivot_wider` suggested in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers; I'll give that a go. A table would be fine, as this table will be an output of the script.

Comment: as a note, you could pass `me_export_data` for the data argument to `xtabs` rather than `summary_tabl` and avoid the code included in the question

Comment: @arsquared please mark as answered if this solved your issue